# Excel: Table not resizing when using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am relatively new to coding in general, but here goes:

I have a huge list of membershipdata which I am trying to organize. This is going to be done weekly as the data is variable, so I am trying to automate the work a bit.

I have written (with help) a code that copies an entire row of data if a specific cell contains a specific text, and pastes it in another sheet under an existing table.

However, when doing this using a macro, the table doesnt resize accordingly, like it would do when using ctrl+c and ctrl+v.
I.e. when there is more data this week then last, the table isnt large enough, and so the sorting options in the table wont sort all the data.

I have been able to resize the table using this code:

```
Sub sortOK()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("OK")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

  Worksheets("OK").UsedRange

  LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  LastColumn = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

  sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

  sht.ListObjects("OK").Resize Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

End Sub
```

This works fine, however it only works when I am viewing this specific sheet, I cant operate it from another sheet.
How can I do so?

I would also like to do the same operation in one go on four other lists, each in its own spreadsheet.

I have been stuck on this problem alost an entire day, and my head is about to explode!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *I have written (with help) a code that copies an entire row of data if a specific cell contains a specific text, and pastes it in another sheet under an existing table*  That's not the code you've shown us. Show us that code.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) about fully qualifying your range objects. Don't use `Select` or `Activate`. Qualify your ranges properly, and you can run a macro regardless of which sheet is active at runtime.

Comment: Always have option explicit at the top of your code for starters.   Fully reference your range objects including the workbook you are using. Also,  i am surprised your are not getting a compile error with Worksheets("OK").UsedRange as you are not setting this to a variable.

Comment: If Worksheets("OK") is in the same workbook as the code then fully qualifying would start to look like  Dim wb As Workbook  Set sht = wb.Worksheets("OK")
    Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")  etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Set StartCell = sht.Range("A1")
```

It should work. This way, you are referencing the worksheet to the range as well. If you do not do it, it takes the `ActiveSheet.Range("A1")`.

Comment: Thank you for your respons, but it didn't work, however my error changed from: "Method "range" of object"_Worksheet" failed"" to "Select-method in Range-class failed".

Both with a "Run-time error "1004".

Comment: @ErikLøkås - write `sht.Select` on the line before the error.

Comment: @ErikLøkås - welcome. You may consider reading this later - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba